# Date.ParseExact issues

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to format a date for an API. the desired format is: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff+HH:mm
(eg. 2022-10-12T09:52:14.1234567+03:00). I'm using Date.ParseExact in the following way:

```
Date.ParseExact("2022-10-12T09:52:14.1234567+03:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff+HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

.

Initially I used 'Now' instead of this string, but then I saw that the string and the desired format have to match. The error I'm getting is 'DateTime pattern 'H' appears more than once with different values.'. Is there a way to avoid that? Also is it possible to use 'Now' in this line?

Thank you

Comment: According to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings the format specifier for the timezone offset is `zzz`

Comment: "Initially i used Now instead of this string" it sounds like you are confusing the input format and the output format. What do you really want, a Datetime that is displaed with a specific format or parse a datetime-string to a `DateTime`? So what means "desired format", do you really get this string in this format, then its not desired but actual, or do you want to return this format, then its desired but not a `Parse`-issue?

Comment: I want to convert the current date and time in this format. This is why I used 'Now'

Comment: This will be used to upload events to an API

Comment: @skipjack: note that i have edited my answer to use `zzz` for the utc offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you don't have a parse issue, you don't need `ParseExact` at all. You have a `Date` and want to return it as a formatted string. Then use [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)) and `zzz` for the utc-offset:

```
string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

Read also: [Custom date and time format strings](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: But wouldnt `+HH:mm` print the hours and minutes of the timestamp instead of the UTC offset?

Comment: @derpirscher: you're probably right, so i've edited the answer